# FileStream Write in VB.NET produces corrupted PDF's

Tags: vb.net

I am downloading Binary from SSRS and writing the Byte Array to a PDF File.
The PDF File is then mailed. I get the email. However, I get the error on opening the attachment. The error is "Adobe Acrobat Reader DC could not open the PDF File because it is not either supported file type or the file has been damaged (for example, it was sent as an email and was not correctly decoded."

Below is the code that writes the PDF File. Also this happens occasionally. Not all the time.

```
Public Sub ExecuteReport()
        Try
            ' Reset Status Flags to initial value of True
            StatusVals(0) = True : StatusVals(1) = True : StatusVals(2) = True

            ' Call the GetBinary Method to download the requested report
            DownloadBinary = GetBinary(
                                                    SetConfigDetails.ReportURLPrefix & Report.gsHyperlink & "&db=" & SetConfigDetails.ReportDBId,
                                                    SetConfigDetails.ReportServerUser,
                                                    SetConfigDetails.ReportServerPassword,
                                                    StatusVals
                                               )

            SyncLock _fileLocker

                If StatusVals(0) Then

                    ' Generate a file path for the export with the file name as well; 
                    FileName = SetFSODetails.TempFolderPath & "\" & Report.gsReportName

                    ' Call the WriteBinary Procedure to create an export from the downloaded response
                    Call WriteBinary(DownloadBinary, FileName, StatusVals)

                    If StatusVals(1) Then

                        ' Call the MailBinary Method to send the exports to all recepients; Changed on the 17th Dec 09
                        Mail.MailBinary(
                                                            SetConfigDetails.MailSMTP,
                                                            SetConfigDetails.MailSMTPPort,
                                                            SetConfigDetails.MailSMTPOnLocalOrRemote,
                                                            SetConfigDetails.MailFrom,
                                                            Report.gsEmail,
                                                            SetConfigDetails.MailBody,
                                                            Report.gsEMailSubject,
                                                            SetConfigDetails.MailCC,
                                                            SetConfigDetails.MailBCC,
                                                            FileName,
                                                            StatusVals,
                                                            ReportNumber,
                                                            Report.gsBatchId,
                                                            SubBatchNumber
                                                        )

                        If StatusVals(2) Then

                            DAccess.UpdateEMailFlag(Report.gsRowId.ToString)

                            Console.WriteLine("Record (" & Report.gsRowId.ToString & ") with Report Number " & ReportNumber.ToString & " Batch No " & Report.gsBatchId & " Sub Batch No " & SubBatchNumber.ToString() & " Processed Successfully...")

                            ' Delete the File once it has been mailed
                            Try
                                Dim FileInfo As New System.IO.FileInfo(FileName)
                                FileInfo.Delete()
                            Catch ex As Exception
                                Console.WriteLine("Error encountered with Report Number " & ReportNumber.ToString() & " with ReportName " & ReportName.ToString() & " : " & ex.Message)
                                Call StartUp.LogMe("Module1.Main.FileInfo", ex.StackTrace, ex.Message)
                            End Try
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End SyncLock
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine("Error encountered with Report Number " & ReportNumber.ToString() & " with ReportName " & ReportName.ToString() & " : " & ex.Message)
            Call StartUp.LogMe("Module1.Main.FileInfo", ex.StackTrace, ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub
Public Sub WriteBinary(ByVal Binary() As Byte, ByVal FileName As String, ByRef Status() As Boolean)
        Dim FStream As FileStream

        Try
            If Directory.Exists(FileName) = False Then
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(FileName))
            End If
            FStream = New FileStream(FileName, FileMode.CreateNew)

            FStream.Write(Binary, 0, Binary.Length)
            FStream.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            ' Explicitly set the status to False
            Status(1) = False
            Console.WriteLine("Error encountered with Report Number " & ReportNumber.ToString() & " with ReportName " & ReportName.ToString() & " : " & ex.Message)
            Call StartUp.LogMe("Module1.WriteBinary", ex.StackTrace, ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: You need to show more code - for starters where you get `Binary` from and how you pass it to the method. The code you have currently shown us does not corrupt the file.

Comment: @VisualVincent - Added more code as per your suggestion.

Comment: Presumably what you get from `GetBinary` is incomplete. Is there any other way you can download the file so you can use that to check how many bytes are missing when your application does it?

Comment: @VisualVincent - There is no other way. This is the only way we do it. Do I need to use Flush before Close method.

Comment: It's better if you wrap the `FileStream` in a [**`Using` block**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx). Could you show me the `GetBinary()` code as well? I've never used SSRS, so I'm afraid I may only help if your issue is related to a coding mistake.

Comment: @VisualVincent - This is not related to multithreading as you pointed out. We are getting corrupted PDF's because of SSRS timeout. Hence the PDF is corrupted.

Comment: I never said it was related to multithreading??? -- Anyhow, glad you found the cause!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with multi-threading. This is because of SSRS timeout which is returning an error.  In the code the GetBinaryMethod is timing out. It gives an Error Response. Hence the PDF is corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, had what sounds like this exact problem - was writing "0's" for the entire file size. Here is my code that works now:

```
Dim dr1 as OracleDataReader
Dim fs as System.IO.FileStream
while dr1.read()
    Dim b(dr1.GetBytes(0,0,Nothing,0,Integer.MaxValue)-1 as Byte
   dr1.getbytes(0,0,b,0,b.Length)
   fs = new system.io.filestream("\filelocation\filename.pdf",IO.FileMode.Create, IO.fileaccess.write)
   fs.write(b.0.b.Length)
   fs.close()
End While
```

Comment: @Breettvd, not sure if I understand this correctly.

Comment: This won't even compile, and when it does you are still constantly overwriting the same file.